# how to distinguish "require"from"involve"?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs

I have just encounter with the explanation in a site. I am wondering if it is right and if you could give a vivid example to clarify it better.

Involvement does not suggest requirement. You can be part of something without being required for it.that is the difference.

Could we use involve instead require but we couldn't use require instead of involve?
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[require](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/require)**
>
> Need for a particular purpose:
>
> > *three patients required operations*
>
> **[involve](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/involve)**
>
> Have or include (something) as a necessary or integral part or result:
>
> > *my job involves a lot of travelling*

You understood **correct**ly: to require is **to need** while to involve is **to imply that something is part or result of**.